# How do I find out if my CPA filed an extension?

Tags: united-states, taxes, extension

I have had my taxes prepared by this CPA in past years. However, for this year, 2015, he advised he filed for an extension. He said there was a problem as I am on Social Security now.

I have sent him numerous emails and his reply he will get it done next week, he has not. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is "How do I find out if my CPA filed an extension". But you give your answer. No. He hasn't. So I'm not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can go through the IRS directly to see if they have received/accepted your extension. The website below will allow you to submit for the transcripts. You could also just call them.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript

As Chris mentioned in his comment, it already sounds like your CPA has said he hasn't done it yet.